# What is the meaning of "Take my advice with this much salt"?

Tags: idioms

[image]

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> Take my advice with this much salt.

There was an image of a lot of salt being attached to this sentence. I guess some kind of humor is being involved but I cannot fully understand it. Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Can you post a link to where you found the sentence and the image?

Comment: it was a chat between colleagues. one asked for advice. Another one suggested something and then said the above sentence and pic :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phrase **take it with a grain of salt** is an English idiom meaning, "Be skeptical about it." The "it" is usually a statement heard from someone else, like a factual claim or advice. It can also mean that while the statement is true, it might include some error or it might not be true when applied in every circumstance; you will need to take care and use common sense when applying it.

The image of a mountain of salt is humor, exaggerating the usual "grain". It suggests that the advice is almost certainly wrong, maybe even deliberately wrong.

---

Historically, the expression **with a grain of salt** comes from reports by the ancient Romans, such as Pliny the Elder in the *Naturalis Historia,* that adding a grain of salt to a certain recipe or to poisons could make you immune to poisons; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_of_salt) for a little more information. Most English speakers today don't hear any reference to poisons when they hear the idiom, but the **grain of salt** vaguely suggests protection from something mildly dangerous in the thing that you are taking it with.

Comment: wow! thanks very much! Perfect explanation. Totally makes sense! :)